# Subclass awakeFromNib to call a superclass custom init/setup method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, storyboard

I have a 3rd-party `UIViewController` that is designed to be initialized with -`(id)initWithURL:(NSURL*)url` only. There are no other `init`-family methods declared. I'd like to subclass this to be used with Storyboard so something like `[super initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]` is called automatically. Design pattern aside, it's just the goal du jour.

I've tried this to no avail in the subclass:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    if ([super respondsToSelector:@selector(initWithUrl:)]) {
        [super performSelector:@selector(initWithUrl:) withObject:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]];
    }
}
```

The above gives a compiler *error* about the selector retaining an object. Now, the superclass `initWithURL:`is just this

```
- (id)initWithUrl:(NSURL *)url {
    // Set url and init views
    _url = url;
    [self setup];
    return self;
}
```

so I've tried to call `[super performSelector:@selector(setup)]` from `awakeFromNib`, but of course the private variable _url cannot be set from the subclass. How can I accomplish this for Storyboard use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to override the `initWithCoder:` init method in your UIViewController subclass. This way you can return a different instance when the UIViewController is being created.

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [super initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]];
    return self;
}
```

Some additional reading about how objects are initialized from the storyboard: [Responding to Being Loaded from a Nib File](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSObject_UIKitAdditions/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/awakeFromNib)

Comment: That's it. Very good write up. I've never used `initWithCoder`, nor storyboard that much. Thank you.